# JSON parsing using python

Tags: python, json

I'm attempting to understand the basics of JSON and thought using some Google translate examples would be interesting. I'm not actually making requests via the API but they have the following example I have saved as "file.json":

```
{
    "data": {
        "detections": [
            [
                {
                    "language": "en",
                    "isReliable": false,
                    "confidence": 0.18397073
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm reading in the file and used simplejson:

```
json_data = open('file.json').read()
json = simplejson.loads(json_data)

>>> json
{'data': {'detections': [[{'isReliable': False, 'confidence': 0.18397073, 'language': 'en'}]]}}
```

I've tried multiple ways to print the value of 'language' with no success. For example, this fails. Any pointers would be appreciated!

```
print json['detections']['language']
```

Comment: `json['data']['detections'][0][0]['language']`. It should be obvious if you look at the structure.

Comment: This is not a `json` issue - you need to learn how to work with Python lists and dictionaries, the native data structures created by `loads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `json['data']['detections'][0][0]['language']`.  As your example data shows, 'language' is a key of a dict that is inside a list that is inside another list that inside the 'detections' dict which is inside the 'data' dict.